# how to provide sizes in image-set similar to sizes in srcset?

Tags: css, background-image, imageset

We are using the background-image style for one component in our application. we need to make it responsive with different resolution images. I have seen that we can make use of **image-set** to achieve it and implemented it as below and working as expected.
Please see the below code snippet I have implemented.

```
<div style="width: 50%;height: 50%;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: -webkit-image-set(
        url(smallCat.jpg) 1x,
        url(BigCat.jpg) 2x)">
</div>
```

Now, I would like to give a specific resolution of the screen in place of 1x,2x.
Since it is possible in **srcset** with **sizes**, do we have any way to set sizes for image-set?
Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, there is no syntax for this. But:

> Another difference, is that unlike with the `srcset` attribute, where you can also give image options based on the width of the browser (when art direction is required), you cannot do that with the `image-set`. However, art direction can still be achieved in CSS using media queries!

Source: [Creating responsive images with image-set](https://uploadcare.com/blog/image-set-for-responsive-images/)

So, if you want to rule all the images using CSS only, use media queries.